# Rest api HttpGet issue

Tags: rest, restresource

I have created a class for api request. I am also sending a parameter in url while requesting for HttpGet. How can I get the value from the url in a HttpGet method. When I added the `RestRequest req, RestResponse res` as parameter to my apex method I am getting an error

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: HTTP GET/DELETE methods do not support parameters at line 4 column 26

Can anyone help me out on this issue. This is my apex class.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/mycall')
global class mycallclass{
  @HttpGet
  global static String getmycall(RestRequest req, RestResponse res) {
    String name = RestRequest.params.get('name');
    return 'WooW Success';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the [params map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm#apex_methods_system_restrequest) via static fields like this:

```
Map<String, String> params = RestContext.request.params;
String name = params.get('name');
```

(Remove the `getmycall` method parameters you presently have in your code.)

Answer (score 1):

You can send the parameter through the URL, and get it by using `RestContext.request` like this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/mycall/*')
global class mycallclass {
    @HttpGet
    global static String getmycall() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        // Get name from url (represented by the * sign)
        String name = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

        // Do Stuff here...

        return 'WooW Success ' + name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note there is a `String.substringAfterLast` (instance) method.